# Waiting for a callback to an async function to complete on button press

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native, async-await

I have three components. A parent, a child and a modal component residing inside the child. The modal must show some data fetched from  the API (called `fetchMyDetails`) and the function resides in the parent. Whenever a button is pressed inside the child, a callback to `fetchMyDetails` is called and data should be passed from the parent to the modal. While the data is fetched, a loading prompt appears until the API call is completed.

**The problem:**

The `await` in `handleButtonPress` method is ignored and the modal is being opened before the data has completed fetching. Why is that?

My parent component:

```
const MyParent= () => {

  // Date pentru solicitare in curs (nota, absenta stearsa sau modificata etc)
  const [myDetails, setMyDetails] = useState<MyDetailsType | null>(null)

  const fetchMyDetails = async () => {

    dispatch((setGlobalLoadingModal(true))); // This is a global modal for loading prompts residing in App.tsx

    myFetchFunction()
      .then((response: MyDetailsType) => {

        if (response.value.length > 0) {
          setMyDetails(response.value)
        }
      })
      .catch(async (error: ApiError) => {
        // ...some error catching
        }
      })
      .finally(() => {
        dispatch((setIsModalLoadingShown(false)));
      })
  }

 return (
 <MyChild myDetails={myDetails} fetchMyDetails={fetchMyDetails}
 )
```

And then I have my child component

```
const MyChilds= ({fetchMyDetails, myDetails}: Props) => {
    
      const [showMyModal, setShowMyModal=useState<boolean>(false);


      const handleButtonPress = async () = > {
       // **THE PROBLEM IS HERE**
       await fetchMyDetails();
       setShowMyModal(true)
      }
    
     return (
     <>
     {showMyModal && 
     <MyModal myDetails={myDetails}/>
     }
     <Button onPress={handleButtonPress}/>
     </>
     )
```

Comment: fetchMyDetails function is async, but there aren't any awaits in it, so it wont wait at all. This is further caused by the direct use of .then/.catch/.finally methods on the promise from myFetchFunction. Use proper async/await there and the problem will go away.

Comment: This is true, but shouldn't using .then inside handleButtonPress fix it?
Something like: 

fetchMyDetails().then(()=>setShowMyModal(true))?

It doesn't.

Comment: No, it won't. The root problem is that you begin a fetch operation and don't await at it, its then method only calls setMyDetails and nothing else. The modal is still opened right away, together with starting the request. If you would like to keep the old then/catch/finally methods you would have to put the modal call inside the then of the fetch, so it shows after it completes. Properly awaiting its promise achieves this.

Comment: try adding a `return` (i.e., `return myFetchFunction().then(...).catch(...)`) to `fetchMyDetails` (and you can remove the `async` keyword). Both return a Promise, but this version returns one that can be awaited

Comment: @Pat Newell Thank you, this is it, this works perfectly without having to rewrite anything else!

Answer (score 1):

You need to make your callback an async function, like so:

```
const handleButtonPress = async () = > {
  await fetchMyDetails();
  setShowMyModal(true)
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I edited my question, the handleButtonPress method is already marked as async but it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue is that you are not awaiting myFetchFunction, the then clause is triggered after the promise is resolved, but fetchMyDetails returns before that:

```
const fetchMyDetails = async () => {
  dispatch((setGlobalLoadingModal(true))); // This is a global modal for loading prompts residing in App.tsx

  try {
    const response: MyDetailsType = await myFetchFunction();

    if (response.value.length > 0) {
      setMyDetails(response.value);
    }
  } catch (error: ApiError) {
    // ...some error catching
  } finally {
    dispatch((setIsModalLoadingShown(false)));
  }
}
```

You can use try/catch like this. or just add await before myFetchFunction();

Answer (score 0):

```js
const MyChild = ({ fetchMyDetails, myDetails }: Props) => {
  const [showMyModal, setShowMyModal] = useState(false);
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);

  const handleButtonPress = async () => {
    setIsLoading(true); //Set loading state
    try {
      await fetchMyDetails();
      setShowMyModal(true);
    } catch (error) {
      // Handle error appropriately
    } finally {
      setIsLoading(false); //Turn off loading state, whether successful or not
    }
  };

  return (
    <>
      {isLoading && <LoadingPrompt />} {/*Show loading prompt while loading*/}
      {showMyModal && <MyModal myDetails={myDetails} />}
      <Button onPress={handleButtonPress} />
    </>
  );
};
```